# Http client Post with body parameter and file in c#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I was trying to attach a `csv` file as a body parameter in my test script. But still as per the below code controller expect file and just curious how should I pass that.

I run test script in below order

**Method-1**

```
public void AttachedRatesFile(string fileName)
            {            
                _form = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)
                    ? _form = new StringContent(string.Empty)
                    : _form = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead($"{ResourceFolder}{fileName}"));
                _form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csv");
                _form.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(fileName);
            }
```

**Method-2**

```
        public void PostRequestExecutes(string resource)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent{_form};
            WhenThePostRequestExecutesWithContent(resource, content);
        }
```

**Method-3**

```
public async void WhenThePostRequestExecutesWithContent(string resource, HttpContent content)
{
    ResponseMessage = await HttpClient.PostAsync(resource, content);
}
```

I see null in below file parameter

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SeedData(IFormFile file)
{
    var result = await _seedDataService.SeedData(file);
    return Ok(new { IsUploadSuccesful = result});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add that to the body as a stream

```
var memoryContentStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryContentStream, Encoding.UTF8, 1000, 
true))
{
  using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
  {
    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, OBJECT);
    jsonTextWriter.Flush();
  }
}

if (memoryContentStream.CanSeek)
{
  memoryContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

Then

```
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(memoryContentStream))
            {
                streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                request.Content = streamContent;

                using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                    response.EnsureIsSuccessStatusCode();

                }
            }
```

The above would first write the content as a memory stream and then when creating the POST request you can send the stream as a streamContent

Comment: My file type is `csv `. Would that make a difference in memory stream code?

Comment: If you want to add any type into the body, you should convert it to a stream so it can be sent over.

Comment: How does one do this without buffering the body?

Comment: @JonathanGilbert You can read the stream after the body has been read rather than the headers in my example. Change the above to HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead. You can also increase the buffer size StreamWriter(memoryContentStream, Encoding.UTF8, BUFFER_SIZE, 
true)

Comment: Huh? I'm asking how you send data in the POST request without it being buffered to an intermediate `MemoryStream`. The existing `HttpContent` implementations specifically support: passing a `byte[]` in as the request body, passing a `ReadOnlyMemory<string>` as the request body, reading from a `Stream` to supply the request body, and using System.Text.Json to serialize your data. You have a problem if you want to dynamically emit the data. The solution presented here works around this by emitting the data to a `MemoryStream` and then using `StreamContent`. How to avoid this intermediate buffer?

Comment: I looked into it a bit more closely, and the `HttpContent` abstract type has a method `SerializeToStreamAsync` that must be implemented. By making a custom `HttpContent`, it is possible to defer actually emitting the body bytes until the actual target `Stream` is available, so that no intermediate in-memory buffering is needed.